# Scala Spark Dataframe Create a new column with maximum of previous and current value of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with only column `category` & column A as below. I want to populate the column B such that, it compares the current value of A and previous value of B and stores the max for each category. Tried with Windows function, lags, max of a categories etc. but the biggest challenge I'm facing is how to remember earlier max while comparing between two values.

```
 +---+--------+--+--+
 id |  category | A | B |
 +---+--------+--+--+
  1  Fruit   1   1
  2  Fruit   5   5
  3  Fruit   3   5 
  4  Fruit   4   5 
  1  Dessert 4   4
  2  Dessert 2   4
  1  Veggies 11  11
  2  Veggies 7   11
  3  Veggies 12  12
  4  Veggies 3   12
  ---+------+---+----+-
```

Comment: how do you define "previous" value?

Comment: Ok,  there's one more column called id,  which is numeric and we've sorted it in ascending order.  Now,  the first row has the first value of A,  and to begin B =A for first row.  For all next rows, B = max ( prev B,  current A).

Comment: if `B = max ( prev B, current A)` then B value in example rows 5,6 should be = 5 ?

Comment: @chlebek, because it's the first element of that category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using running maximum of `A` should do the trick:

```
df
 .withColumn("B", max($"A").over(Window.partitionBy($"category").orderBy($"id")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time expressing this with Spark SQL, but managed with Functional Programming using the Dataset API

```
scala>   case class Food(category: String, a: Int, b: Option[Int] = None)
defined class Food

scala>     val ds = spark.createDataset(
     |       List(
     |         Food("Fruit", 1),
     |         Food("Fruit", 5),
     |         Food("Fruit", 3),
     |         Food("Fruit", 4),
     |         Food("Dessert", 4),
     |         Food("Dessert", 2),
     |         Food("Veggies", 11),
     |         Food("Veggies", 7),
     |         Food("Veggies", 12),
     |         Food("Veggies", 3)
     |       )
     |     )
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Food] = [category: string, a: int ... 1 more field]

scala> ds.show
+--------+---+----+
|category|  a|   b|
+--------+---+----+
|   Fruit|  1|null|
|   Fruit|  5|null|
|   Fruit|  3|null|
|   Fruit|  4|null|
| Dessert|  4|null|
| Dessert|  2|null|
| Veggies| 11|null|
| Veggies|  7|null|
| Veggies| 12|null|
| Veggies|  3|null|
+--------+---+----+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    ds.groupByKey(_.category)
      .flatMapGroups { (key, iter) =>
        if (iter.hasNext) {
          val head = iter.next
          iter.scanLeft(head.copy(b = Some(head.a))) { (x, y) =>
            val a = x.b.map(b => if(x.a > b) x.a else b).getOrElse(x.a)
            y.copy(b = if(y.a > a) Some(y.a) else Some(a))
          }
        } else iter
      }
      .show

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+--------+---+---+
|category|  a|  b|
+--------+---+---+
| Veggies| 11| 11|
| Veggies|  7| 11|
| Veggies| 12| 12|
| Veggies|  3| 12|
| Dessert|  4|  4|
| Dessert|  2|  4|
|   Fruit|  1|  1|
|   Fruit|  5|  5|
|   Fruit|  3|  5|
|   Fruit|  4|  5|
+--------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for taking so much effort to solve the problem Ryan. Dataset was not an option for me because we're only working with Dataframe and occasionally rdd. If I couldn't have solve the problem by using dataframe (please seee above Raphael's solution) I must have take your solution and apply in rdd. Thanks again.